# xml not loading into href

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm attempting to load in data from an XML file with javascript, and it all works 100% fine except the link. If I replace the `createDetails(i,"LINK")` a string, it works fine except that I need it to change for each entry in the XML. But with the `createDetails(i,"LINK")` in, the link is undefined.html and the link instance in the XML is just printed off to the side.

The code:

Preloading the xml:

```
var x;
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HOME");

function createDetails(refNum,tagName){
    var tempProduct; 
    tempProduct = x[refNum].getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.write(tempProduct);
}

function createImage(refNum,tagName){
    var tempProduct; 
    tempProduct = x[refNum].getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    return(tempProduct);
}
```

Script to print it (the broken stuff):

```
<script>
     for(i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
         /*this line doesn't work*/ document.write("<a href=\"" + createDetails(i,"LINK") + ".html\">");
         document.write("<div class=\"homeLink\">");
         document.write("<div class=\"homeLinkPic\">");
         document.write("<img src=\"images/" + createImage(i,"PIC") + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" alt=\"linkpic\" />"); 
         document.write("</div>");
         document.write("<div class=\"productDesc\">");
         createDetails(i,"DESC");
         document.write("</div>");
         document.write("</div>");
         document.write("</a>");
     }
</script>
```

Comment: `createDetails` has no return clause. What do you want to concatenate with `+` if it does not return anything?

Answer (score 2):

`createDetails` isn't returning a value. Change it to:

```
function createDetails(refNum,tagName){
    var tempProduct; 
    tempProduct = x[refNum].getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    return tempProduct;
}
```

Comment: See my comment on the other answer

Comment: I suggest you have two different functions: `createDetails()` that just returns the string, and `writeDetails()` that writes it. Or pass a third argument to `createDetails` that says whether the string should be written or returned.

Comment: I also suggest you stop using `document.write()`. It's a horrible way to update the page. Use DOM functions.

Comment: Or I could just change the link from `createDetails` to `createImage` which has a return clause. And please bear in mind I've only just started learning XML/Javascript in the past month.

Comment: This has very little to do with learning XML. Your problem is entirely in Javascript -- you're trying to use one function in two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value from the `createDetails` function. Try

`return tempProduct;`

instead of

`document.write(tempProduct);`

Comment: While that fixes the problem, it breaks the `createDetails(i,"DESC");` and that part doesn't show at all

Comment: Can you try it like `document.write("<div class=\"productDesc\">" + createDetails(i, "DESC"));` instead of as shown in question?